# Are there different HTML5 doctypes?

Tags: html, doctype

When I use to write pages in XHTML. I had 3 types of `doctype` - `strict`, `transitional` and `frameset`.

Do we have them in HTML5?

Comment: javascript jquery css xml - how exactly were these tags related to your question?!

Comment: @Ashwin accept at least one answer as accepted, if issue resolved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, HTML5 is just HTML5, there are no subsets.

Answer (score 6):

No, the `HTML5 doctype`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

is unique, since it was chosen as the shortest doctype (string) able to turn all current browser (even IE6, afaik) [in standard mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode#Mode_differences_and_examples) (and it can be written in upper/mixed case)

Answer (score 6):

the html5 doctype is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

When you use the new **HTML5 DOCTYPE**, it triggers browsers to render the page in **standards compliant mode**.

**Standards-compliant mode**

- In standards-compliant mode, the web browser assumes the page has been authored to the web content specification declared; code that does not conform to the declared standard may not display, or may display incorrectly.
- For a web browser’s standards-compliant mode to be triggered, the webpage must have a complete document type declaration, including the URI to the document type definition (DTD).
- There is typically less variation in webpage display between different browsers when standards-compliant mode is triggered, as the same centralised W3C specification is used as a reference when creating the web browser software.

Courtesy this [link](http://www.motive.co.nz/glossary/quirks-mode.php)

Answer (score 5):

HTML 5 requires a doctype for legacy compatibility. It has a short doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>` and a long doctype `<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">` The long doctype is only for systems that cannot generate the short one. - [HTML 5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/syntax.html#the-doctype)

Answer (score 4):

There is but one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 3):

The standard [required preamble](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/syntax.html#the-doctype) in the HTML serialisation of HTML5 (i.e. when served as `text/html`) is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Some HTML generators, most notably XSLT, have difficulty creating the above doctype. They may use

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
```

In the XML serialisation of HTML5 (i.e. when served as `application/xhtml+xml`), the doctype may be either of the above, or it may be omitted entirely.

Note that these variations are not like strict, transitional or frameset. What is valid and invalid in HTML5 is the same for each of the above variations - leaving aside the orthogonal matter of differences between HTML and XML syntax.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 has only one and that is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: You may need to take a look at any answers already present before you jump in. In this case, your answer is basically a clone of an answer given over a month ago. Just +1 that one instead in such an event.